# mule read single file from classpath during flow

Tags: mule

Is there an easy way to configure a Flow to read a single file from the classpath one time? I don't need to poll for a file. I just need to read a known file and set its contents as the message payload.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `set-payload` message processor and a MEL expression:

```
<set-payload value="#[Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('my-file.abc')]" />
```

Comment: Actually...this seems to set the payload to be an InputStream. Is there an easy way to make it a String?

Comment: Flank it by an `object-to-string-transformer`.

Comment: I was also able to do this...  <set-payload value="#[groovy:Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('placeidcheckin.xml').text]"/>

Answer (score 7):

For some reason I cannot make the solution proposed by David Dossot to work. I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022839/how-do-i-load-a-resource-and-use-its-contents-as-a-string-in-spring/14022842#14022842) and came up with another solution

```
<spring:bean id="myResource" class="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" factory-method="toString">
    <spring:constructor-arg value="classpath:path/to/myResource.txt" type="java.io.InputStream"/>
</spring:bean>
```

and then you can use set-payload in the following way

```
<set-payload value="#[app.registry.myResource]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

which will result in setting the payload with the content of the file as a String.

This method has the advantage that the content of the resource file is loaded only once into a bean of type String. So if your set-payload statement is executed frequently, this could improve performance.

Comment: I also was not having success with David Dossot's answer. Also, this answer is cleaner and more readable. It should really be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

As of Mule 3.4, use the parse-template transformer

```
<parse-template location="my-resurce.txt" doc:name="Load resource as a String"/>
```

This will make things MUCH easier.

You may need to still set the mime-type though depending on how you are going to use the template.

Common errors include using the full path in the transformer like c:\users\myusers\mule\myfile.txt
That won't compile well.

You can also use Mule Expression in the parse template and Rich text for example.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Parse+Template+Reference

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution seems to be using the dedicated `getResource()` method as described in the
[MUnit documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.3/mock-message-processor#loading-payloads-from-files-and-scripts).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <scripting:component doc:name="Get xls File">                                        
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[new File('C:/project/src/main/resources/account.xls').getText('UTF-8')]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<parse-template location="my-resurce.txt" doc:name="Load resource as a String"/>
```

The file can perfectly contain no MEL expression whatsoever, in which case it's actually loaded as it is, and it becomes the payload.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to throw Java class transformer so you can use the following

> note : the path is the direct package that contain the file you want
>   to read am store the path inside mule variable and then read the file
>   content and stor its value into Payload

.

```
public class PayloadFileReader extends AbstractMessageTransformer {
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
        throws TransformerException {

    String result = "";
    try {
        result = readFileTest(message.getInvocationProperty("path")
                .toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    message.setPayload(result);
    return message;
}


public String readFileTest(String path) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, Exception {


    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

"+classLoader.getResource("samples/v3/addVal-request.sample").getFile());

    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(path).getFile());
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Spring Bean" which tries to "import" the file (Suppose Mule XML conefiguration file). Sample code below:

```
<spring:beans>
 <spring:import resource="classpath:sample-mule-integration.xml"/>
</spring:beans>
```

Or else you can try by placing the file in a property placeholder as below

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:E:\NewMuleWorkSpace\springbeanproperties\src\main\resources\property.properties"/>
```

Or else you can even read the file by using a Groovy component with sample code:

```
 File file = new File("C://Users//schiraboina//Desktop//123.txt")
payload=file.getText()
```