# Mock ups in Mule Esb web services

Tags: web-services, testing, mocking, mule

I have some web service (CXF) on Mule Esb (3.4). At the current moment I try to find the simple way to set up web service response that I need for UAT. I read a lot of information in the internet and as I understood there is a special framework Munit for all types of testing. But, it seems, this framework is used for more complex things than I need. So, could anybody recommend me a simple way to force Mule Esb return predefined xml response. It will be fine if I create an xml response as xml document, upload it in any folder and Mule will send it as response when I call a web service. Thank you for any info for solving my task.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably upload the example responses to the classpath and then, in your flows just load that file and set it as payload.

See this other stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203458/mule-read-single-file-from-classpath-during-flow) around how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 flows.

1 flow for production with the Webservice implementation and 1 flow for UAT testing which returns you just a predefined XML (for example via the http endpoint).

Put both files in a seperate file and make a mule-deploy.properties file for both UAT and Production where you include the corect flows respectivly.