# Getting file path in java transformer from project using servlet in mule esb

Tags: java, servlets, xsd, mule, xml-validation

```
File schemaLocation = new File("/home/localpc/servletaddequi/src/main/resources/BackupSample/DEMO.xsd")
```

I am able to get file if i am passing the file path as mentioned above.
But i want to pass the path of file from project only,how can i pass the path of file? If I pass the file path as below:

```
File schemaLocation = new File("/foldername/filename.xsd");
```

It generates error as :

```
Failed to read schema document 'file:/BackupSample/DEMO.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:347)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4166)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4149)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHandler.java:2479)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:573)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:575)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:541)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:252)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:627)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:643)
    at com.test.Test.transformMessage(Test.java:38)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:141)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:89)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1602)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1509)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /BackupSample/DEMO.xsd (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:619)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2175)
    ... 218 more
```

Comment: Can you add your flow.xml. Why do you need to use a file in the Java transformer . I am a bit confused for the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to an answer from this post: [mule read single file from classpath during flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203458/mule-read-single-file-from-classpath-during-flow), you can use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("filename.xsd")` to get the `URL` class.

Therefore you can try the following code:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("filename.xsd");
File schemaLocation = new File(url.getFile());
```